# using join-path in a method call

Tags: .net, powershell, method-call

Trying to write to a file and did the following:

```
$obj = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList join-path $pwd foo.txt
```

This threw an error

```
PS C:\code\misc> $obj = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList Join-Path $pwd foo.txt
New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\code\misc'.
At line:1 char:18
+ $obj = New-Object <<<<  System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList Join-Path $pwd foo.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

So am I forced to use a variable for the join-path part? I know I could use `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()` but I just wanted an alternative to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis around the Join-Path bit should do the trick.

```
$obj = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList (join-path $pwd foo.txt)
```